# How to know what exactly is being written or which process is keeping my storage disk busy?

Tags: process, memory, disk, storage

I have a server , which has gone rogue(not really), i ran `nmon` and saw that its Disk utilization is BAD, its **100%** busy writing!! Here is the output :

[image]

Can someone tell me what is keeping my disk busy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) is your friend (assuming your server runs Linux).

Comment: on it.. i am also concerned about the default IO scheduler though

Comment: % 99.99 % [jbd2/xvda1-8] This keeps UP ALL THE TIME